# Why am I getting a 400 Bad Request error when visiting domain?

Tags: nginx, dns

My website has been down for 2 months, I've basically given up resolving this issue, I have been talking with DO support as well as posting on stackoverflow and nobody seems to be able to help me.

Setup: Digital Ocean 1-click install of django, ubuntu, nginx

Issue: After setting up a domain, visiting that domain results in a 400 error. visiting the IP works with no problem. I purchased the domain using Google Domains and used the custom name server option and put:

```
ns1.digitalocean.com
ns2.digitalocean.com
ns3.digitalocean.com
```

In etc/nginx/sites-available/django I have:

```
upstream app_server { 
server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0; 
}

server { 
listen 80 default_server; 
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html; 
index index.html index.htm;

client_max_body_size 4G; 
server_name cannablr.com www.cannablr.com;

keepalive_timeout 5;

# Your Django project's media files - amend as required 
location /media { 
alias /home/django/django/dealr/dealr/media; 
}

# your Django project's static files - amend as required 
location /static { 
alias /home/django/django/dealr/dealr/static; 
} 

location /favicon.ico { 
alias /home/django/django/dealr/favicon.ico; 
}

location / { 
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
proxy_redirect off; 
proxy_pass http://app_server; 
} 
}
```

I have this file symlinked inside etc/nginx/sites-enabled.

Another thing that may be worth noting is even though I get a 400 error when visiting the domain, it still loads the favicon.  NO errors in the error log (error logging is configured)

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22804782/1902587

Comment: I definitely did not include the domain in allowed_hosts, let me try this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to add this`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ("yourdomain.com",)`

Comment: comma is required after "yourdomain"?

Comment: I can't believe that was it.  It works now, thank you so much